# Cannot delete a named pipe from Java

Tags: java, named-pipes, nosuchfileexception

I'm creating a named pipe in Java, which is working with the following code:

```
final String [] mkfifo = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "mkfifo ~/myFifo && tail -f ~/myFifo | csh -s"};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mkfifo);
```

But now I'm getting a `NoSuchFileException` when I try to delete it with this code:

```
Path fifoPath = Paths.get("~/myFifo");

try {
    Files.delete(fifoPath);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

I have verified that the file is, indeed, being created by issuing an `ls ~` during execution of the program, and `~/myFifo` still remains after the exception is thrown and execution of the program ends.

I assumed the `... && tail ...` may cause some problems in case that it is somehow blocking, so I made the change to creating the named pipe with this:

```
final String [] mkfifo = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "mkfifo ~/myFifo"};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mkfifo);
```

The pipe is still created, which is fine. I've also attempted to remove the pipe in a less-native Java way, via `exec`:

```
final String [] rmfifo = { "/bin/rm ~/myFifo" };

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rmfifo);
```

None of these seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks,
erip

Comment: Can you show the error that is being thrown?

Comment: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ~/myFifo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `~/myFifo`.

Java isn't understanding the `~`

I ran the following code.

```
Path fifoPath = Paths.get("/home/russell/myFifo");
try {
    Files.delete(fifoPath);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

And it ran perfectly.

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
Path fifoPath = Paths.get(home + "/myFifo");
try {
    Files.delete(fifoPath);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

The above code also works on my system.

`~/` is a `shell` thing, so java won't pick it up.

The reason it's actually creating the file in the first place is because you're using `/bin/sh` to run the `mkfifo` command, and `sh` translates the `~/`.

Comment: This worked. Running into some other problems, but it's unrelated. Thank you very much!